# RNCamera size and styling

Tags: react-native

I am currently trying to use `RNCamera` and it is all smooth except styling, which is very hard to control, what I have tried so far is wrap it in view and adjust and give it flex: 1 and just play with the view style props like this:

```
<View style ={{height: screenWidth, width: screenWidth}}>// custom styles basically
    <RNCamera style = {{flex:1, width: '100%'}}>
</ View>
```

Is there a way to fully control the RNCam size and styles??

Answer (score 0):

in the style of the RNCam alignSelf: 'stretch'